# Nginx Core Dump

Tags: nginx

In my Nginx, I keep getting:

```
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94913 open socket #39 left in connection 8
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94899 open socket #23 left in connection 9
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94886 open socket #32 left in connection 15
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94903 open socket #40 left in connection 24
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94911 open socket #17 left in connection 31
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94895 open socket #37 left in connection 36
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94909 open socket #43 left in connection 40
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94898 open socket #20 left in connection 47
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94887 open socket #33 left in connection 54
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94893 open socket #36 left in connection 55
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94890 open socket #35 left in connection 58
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94889 open socket #34 left in connection 63
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: *94896 open socket #18 left in connection 71
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 35#35: aborting
2020/10/02 06:08:08 [alert] 33#33: worker process 35 exited on signal 6 (core dumped)
```

So I enabled a core dump by adding this to my nginx.conf

```
worker_rlimit_core  500M;
working_directory /tmp;
debug_points abort;
```

When the core is dumped, I used gdp as such:

```
gdb /usr/sbin/nginx  /tmp/somecorefile.xxxx
backtrace full
```

And I am getting this output.

```
warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/35' in core file.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `nginx: worker pr'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/35' in core file.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace full
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
        set = {__val = {0, 93898407404718, 206158430256, 140725383938616, 140725383938416, 712653358923658240, 2, 6, 93898408092161, 2, 6, 8, 93898411815600, 
            140725383938672, 140725383938600, 140725383938672}}
        pid = <optimized out>
        tid = <optimized out>
        ret = <optimized out>
#1  0x00007fc51604f535 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
        save_stage = 1
        act = {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = 0x7fc515dc62c0, sa_sigaction = 0x7fc515dc62c0}, sa_mask = {__val = {712653358923658240, 140484452045760, 
              0, 140484452041200, 140484451262672, 1, 0, 93898411799280, 93898407566008, 140484451264536, 12, 93898408473376, 0, 140484452049600, 
              140484452057768, 93898411799280}}, sa_flags = 368698904, sa_restorer = 0x55666d7af2f0}
        sigs = {__val = {32, 0 <repeats 15 times>}}
#2  0x000055666d377613 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x000055666d3a2d68 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x000055666d3a3a22 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x000055666d3a1dc3 in ngx_spawn_process ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x000055666d3a2fd0 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x000055666d3a4654 in ngx_master_process_cycle ()
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x000055666d3782bb in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

And this one is a separate core dump

```
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/nginx...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 26510]

warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/26510' in core file.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `nginx: worker pr'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

warning: Unexpected size of section `.reg-xstate/26510' in core file.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace full
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
        set = {__val = {0, 9223372036854775807, 0, 0, 0, 60, 5, 0, 1288, 0, 10, 94846235324710, 1, 0, 94846235939456, 3560692332834648576}}
        pid = <optimized out>
        tid = <optimized out>
        ret = <optimized out>
#1  0x00007f0e3ff4d535 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
        save_stage = 1
        act = {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = 0x56431c2a3268, sa_sigaction = 0x56431c2a3268}, sa_mask = {__val = {3560692332834648576, 94846233719536, 
              0, 139699176612336, 139699175833808, 1, 0, 94846233719536, 94846217345720, 139699175834328, 12, 94846218253088, 0, 139699176624816, 
              139699176621944, 94846233719536}}, sa_flags = 1072285208, sa_restorer = 0x56431c11b2f0}
        sigs = {__val = {32, 0 <repeats 15 times>}}
#2  0x000056431b14f613 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x000056431b17ad68 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x000056431b17ba22 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x000056431b179dc3 in ngx_spawn_process ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x000056431b17afd0 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x000056431b17c654 in ngx_master_process_cycle ()
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x000056431b1502bb in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

My nginx version is such:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.2
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-dav-ext --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Cjs4TR/nginx-1.14.2/debian/modules/http-subs-filter
```

Does anyone know what any of this means? And is this the correct place to report this problem?